# Database diagram support objects cannot be installed because this > database does not have a valid owner

Tags: sql, sql-server

Перенес базу с одного ПК на другой, но при попытке создания Database Diagram появляется вот такая ошибка:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Database diagram support objects cannot be installed because this
>   database does not have a valid owner.  To continue, first use the
>   Files page of the Database Properties dialog box or the ALTER
>   AUTHORIZATION statement to set the database owner to a valid login,
>   then add the database diagram support objects.
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У твоей БД нету владельца, тебе его надо установить в Контекстном меню File затем открыть диалоговое окно Database Properties, и в нём же выставить владельца, Удачи.